# How to add row in html table on top of specific row?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, tablerow

I have a table, and each row has a button to add a new row on top of it. Each row has new inputs.

I know how to add a row on top of the table, but not on top of each row that I'm clicking on the button. Would anyone have a tip on how to solve it? I might be able to do it, but the solution I see is very complicated, and I'm sure there must be a smarter solution.

Oh, also I don't know how to update the parameter sent in the `insertNewRow(id)` function.
So far this is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertNewRow(id){
    var row = document.getElementById("bottomRow");
    var newrow = row.cloneNode(true);
    console.log(newrow);
    var newInputs = newrow.getElementsByTagName('input');

    var allRows = row.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    row.parentNode.insertBefore(newrow, row);

    var i=row.rowIndex;
    console.log(i);

}
</script>


<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Title1:</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Title2:</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Title3:</td>    
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td><input class="c1" readonly maxlength="9" size="7" id="gTop" type="text" value ="11"></td>
        <td> <-></td>
        <td id="l1"><input class="c2"  style="width:35px;" maxlength="9" size="7" type="text" id="lTop" value="33"></td>
        <td>=</td>
        <td id="rv1"><input id="rvTop" input class="c2"  style="width:105px;" maxlength="100" size="37" type="text" value="blahblahblah"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>x</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="bottomRow">                 
        <td><input class="c1" readonly maxlength="9" size="7" id="gBottom" type="text" value =""></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td id="l1"><input class="c2"  style="width:35px;" maxlength="9" size="7" type="text" id="lBottom" value="11"></td>
        <td>=</td>
        <td id="rv1"><input id="rvBottom" input class="c2"  style="width:105px;" maxlength="100" size="37" type="text" value="blahblahblah"></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="insertNewRow(1)">+</button></td>
        <td>x</td>                      
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery in your solution? It would make things a lot easier imo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't use jQuery (it's not my choice..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onclick` attribute, instead of just calling `insertNewRow()`, do something like

```
insertNewRow.apply(this);
```

The `this` keyword inside the `onclick` attribute is a reference of the clicked element. With `insertNewRow.apply(this)`, we'll be calling `insertNewRow()` and at the same time, assign the `this` keyword inside that function call to the clicked element or in this case, the button (if we don't do that, `this` inside `insertNewRow()` will be a reference to the `Window` object instead). Then in, your `insertNewRow()` function, check if the current element being clicked on is a `tr` element. If not, go up by one level and see if that element is a `tr` element. Keep doing that until you get to the first `tr` element. So, basically you'll be searching for the closest `tr` element.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="insertNewRow.apply(this);">+</button>
```

```js
function insertNewRow(){
    var row = null,
        el = this;
    // Get the closest tr element
    while (row === null)
    {
        if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr')
        {
            row = el; // row is now the closest tr element
            break;
        }
        el = el.parentNode;                 
    }

    // Rest of the code here

}​
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfnZa/1/)

If you're still not sure what `Function.apply()` is, take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).